# Adding comments to specific model in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Currently i am creating Blog using rails,where i want to add comments to post model. I am using acts_as_commentable,its works great on rails console but when i try to implement it in MVC,I got confused !! how can i add comments to Post model.

What should i do ? is there need to create any new controller for handle comments?

I want add comment form below the post->show view,so that user can add comments on the posts#show page.

Sorry for my english !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `acts_as_commentable` as Paulo suggested or `polymorphic-association`

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association

or with PRO account on railscasts: http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association-revised (repo: https://github.com/railscasts/154-polymorphic-association-revised/tree/master/blog-after)

a little modified code below, this code will let you add comments to `Post` only as we load `@commentable` with `@commentable = Post.find(params[:id])`, if you will go through tutorial you'll be able to add comments to any other models in the app where User and Post share the same Comment model.

I used `acts_as_commentable` in my app before, nice gem, but I am using `polymorphic-association` now cause it is much more customizable.

**post.rb**

```
  attr_accessible :content, :name
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
```

**comment.rb**

```
  attr_accessible :content
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<h1>Comments</h1>  

<ul id="comments">  
  <% @comments.each do |comment| %>  
    <li><%= comment.content %></li>  
  <% end %>  
</ul>  

<h2>New Comment</h2>  
<%= form_for [@commentable, @comment] do |f| %> 
  <ol class="formList">  
    <li>  
      <%= f.label :content %>  
      <%= f.text_area :content, :rows => 5 %>  
    </li>  
    <li><%= f.submit "Add comment" %></li>  
  </ol>  
<% end %>
```

**posts_controller**

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @commentable = @post
  @comments = @commentable.comments
  @comment = Comment.new
end
```

**comments_controller**

```
  def create
    @commentable = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new(params[:comment])
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Comment created."
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end
```

Comment: what changes should be in routes.config file for comments_controller

Comment: +1 @AkashShinde : Here's example app for [154-polymorphic-association-revised](https://github.com/railscasts/154-polymorphic-association-revised/tree/master/blog-after). But if you want using `acts_as_commentable` here's basic [commenting system - acts_as_commentable](http://www.arailsdemo.com/posts/16)

Comment: @anonymousxxx thank you for the link to arailsdemo, they have some nice tutorials there.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see by the [acts_as_commentable](https://github.com/jackdempsey/acts_as_commentable) documentation,

Also make sure you have the migrations to create the database structure.

In your model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_commentable
end
```

By your comment I see you are giving the first steps on Rails. You need to create the controller and views. In you controller you'll need to initialize the variables and call the respecting view.
My best advise for you, is before starting doing your own blog, take a look at [this Rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book), which will cover most of the aspects you'll need.

Comment: yeah i added this method to my model,its working via rails console perfectly i can comment to that post succesfully via console but i want to add comment to that particular post via form in posts#show.is there is need to create new controller or what is the other way ?